# python3 not working in virtual environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, conda

First I installed **anaconda 2** and created virtual environment with **python 2.7** and it's working fine.
But I created another environment with **python 3** and in this environment inside jupyter notebook and there is kernel error.
Is there any problem in creating two environment with different python version??How can I solve it?
(*First environment is still working fine*)

[this is what prompt showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnnBq.png)

[this is jupyter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjIa9.png)

Comment: Please, follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question. Show us the error, explain what did you try to solve it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can make different virtual environments for different versions of Python. you  should create your environments using the command:

```
conda create -n yourenvname1 python=2.7 anaconda
```

and the other environment by typing the command

```
conda create -n yourenvname2 python=3.7 anaconda
```

Be sure to activate whichever environment you wish to use. In the above lines enter whichever version of python you have.